# Xamarin forms: how to turn on all switches in a Listview?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have a switch inside a Listview. I need to turn on all the switches when selecting an option from `DisplayActionSheet`. How can I do this feature?

**Xaml Code:**

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="UserList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label 
                            Text="{Binding fullname}"
                            Font="11" 
                            TextColor="Black"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                            VerticalOptions="Center"/> 

                        <Switch 
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Update to Nikil

Added `IsToggled="{Binding IsSelected}"` to switch and added `public bool IsSelected { get; set; }` in model. But getting error for the code added inside `DisplayActionSheet`. Screenshot adding below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the shared sample project of discussion, binding model is **webContentList** from web API. If want selected method work , first need to add property(`IsSelected`) in it, and add **INotifyPropertyChanged**.

```
public class webContentList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string swcmMessage { get; set; }
    public string pageTitle { get; set; }
    public Modifier modifier { get; set; }
    public bool deletable { get; set; }
    public string pageContentType { get; set; }
    public string previewUUID { get; set; }
    public int webContentDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public long pageCreatedTime { get; set; }
    public int userCreated { get; set; }
    public string pageStatus { get; set; }
    public string thumbnailImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string videoUrl { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    public int webContentId { get; set; }
    public Creator creator { get; set; }
    public string contentTemplateId { get; set; }
    public string appName { get; set; }
    public string customHTML { get; set; }
    public string processedTime { get; set; }
    public string pageDesc { get; set; }
    public string editUrl { get; set; }
    public string pageKwd { get; set; }
    public bool staticContent { get; set; }
    public int siteId { get; set; }
    public string pageUrl { get; set; }
    public string linkType { get; set; }
    public long pageUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string swcmStatus { get; set; }
    public int userModified { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public bool isProfileImageNull { get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(thumbnailImageUrl); } }

    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then in **MenuOptions** method , can modify as follow :

```
public async void MenuOptions(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string action = await DisplayActionSheet(null, "Cancel", null, "Select All");
    if (action == "Select All")
    {
        //List<TweetTopicsResponse> ItemSource = ItemSource(x => { x.IsSelected = true; return x; }).ToList();
        List<webContentList> itemSource = AdminTopicList.ItemsSource as List<webContentList>;
        foreach(webContentList item in itemSource)
        {
            item.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is [the Modified Project link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8k5t0cbdtuw1z36/SwitchSample.rar?dl=0) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a bool property called IsSelected in the Model with which you are binding the ListView.
That Model should Implement INotifyPropertyChanged. 
Then you can bind the IsToggled="{Binding IsSelected}".

On the selecting that option from DisplayActionSheet.

```
List ItemSource = ItemSource(x => {x. IsSelected = true; return x;}).ToList()
```

Comment: Can you explain little more, I didn't get the first part.

Comment: You need to have a class which will have the Properties string fullName and bool IsSelected. And that Class needs to implement BaseViewModel or ObservableObject, which in turn implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot, can you please have a look.

Comment: What is the Model class that you are using ?

Comment: I have added the Model class name in angle brackets, but getting use of unassigned local variable 'ItemSource' error

Comment: This DisplayActionSheet Method should call a method from ViewModel. And Itemsource should be an List in the ViewModel and not the code behind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198349/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-nikhil).